# Css Family Tree no wrap

Tags: css

I'm trying to make that css plugin to work with no wrapping but I failed. Here is the [tutorial](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-family-tree) I'm following.

Is there any solution to make it no wrap?

This is how it looks like: https://jsfiddle.net/jhkvpxLg/

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.tree ul {
  padding-top: 20px; 
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.tree li {
  float: left; 
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.tree li::before, .tree li::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 50%; height: 20px;
}
.tree li::after{
  right: auto; left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.tree li:only-child::after, 
.tree li:only-child::before {
  display: none;
}
.tree li:only-child{ padding-top: 0;}
.tree li:first-child::before, 
.tree li:last-child::after{
  border: 0 none;
}
.tree li:last-child::before{
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child::after{
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}
.tree ul ul::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 0; height: 20px;
}
.tree li a{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.tree li a:hover, 
.tree li a:hover+ul li a {
  background: #c8e4f8; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}
.tree li a:hover+ul li::after, 
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before{
  border-color:  #94a0b4;
}
```

```html
<!--
We will create a family tree using just CSS(3)
The markup will be simple nested lists
-->
<div class="tree">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Parent</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a></li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What part of the tree you want to make not wrap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Remove `float:left` from `.tree li` (no longer needed) and
- add `display:flex` to `.tree ul`.

[`fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/kapn7cjd/)

Don't forget to run your final CSS through [`autoprefixer`](https://autoprefixer.github.io/).

Comment: That's what I need.<br>Thank you so much.